Was Jesus Christ's soul ever created, or has it existed forever?
I address this question to Christians who believe that Jesus Christ possesses both divine and human natures—those who believe that Christ has always been the Son of God, that is, God, and, since the moment of His incarnation, also the Son of Man, that is, a human. In other words, I address the following three main branches of Christianity: the Roman Catholic Church, the Eastern Orthodox Church, and mainstream Protestantism (those Protestant believers who directly address Jesus in their prayers): Was Jesus Christ's soul ever created, or has it existed forever?
On the one hand, as the Son of God, Christ, being divine, has always possessed a soul—that is, the ability to have thoughts, feelings, and will. Verses like this one seem to indicate that:

“Jerusalem, Jerusalem... how often I have longed to gather your
children together” (Matthew 23:37, NIV) (clearly, the longing here extends over a period of more than 33 and a half years)

In other words, at His incarnation, Christ only received a physical body, which seems to be confirmed by this verse:

"Therefore, when Christ came into the world, he said: ‘Sacrifice and
offering you did not desire, but a body you prepared for me’" (Hebrews
10:5, NIV).

On the other hand, from the moment of His incarnation, Christ possessed human nature. A key element of human nature is the possession of a created soul, not just a physical body. If so, then Jesus Christ should also possess a created human soul—regardless of when exactly it was created (whether at the moment of conception or at some point prior). If that is the case, then which of the two options is correct:

Was it like His divine soul simply entered His created human soul and the two joined as one, and thus, showing no contradictions to each other and abiding in perfect harmony and agreement, can be considered one soul, one personality?

Or is it like, rather, in case with Jesus there is only His uncreated divine soul that Christ has always posessed eternally, and the absence of a created human soul does not exclude Him from being fully human (just as the absence of a biological human father does not)?


How is this matter viewed in the above-mentioned branches of Christianity?

Chalcedonian Christianity teaches Jesus had a complete human nature, including a human soul. The idea that Jesus's humanity was limited to his physical body is called Apollinarianism, and is considered heresy.

William Huntington wrote a booklet called 'The Soul of Christ' which is one of the most spiritual books I have ever read. I recommend the book if you can find it. I have in mind to re-publish it myself some time. The answer in Mr Huntington's book is a decided would be a decided 'no'. The word 'nephesh' (soul) in Hebrew is sometimes applied to Deity but in my judgment that should not be misunderstood and should be seen as 'the heart' and not be confused with a human soul.

Given all the comments, you might want to reword the question without using the word "soul". Clearly various people have different ideas as to what that word means, and from a biblical perspective "soul" refers to what people (and animals) are, not what they have; plus, biblical souls can die. ¶ Perhaps you really mean "spirit"?

@RayButterworth - Sorry, but I would rather stick to my original usage of the word "soul" - the fact, that others have different understanding of the term doesn't necessarily mean that their understanding is correct and mine is wrong. Besides, I disagree that biblical souls can die. It all, of course, depends on what you mean by "die", too, but then again - I still have the right to use the word "die" in my sense. Plus, I can't predict what sense you attach to it. So, it's better to go by the way of gradual clarification of what we mean by this or that term rather than changing terms .

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

John1:18 Jesus is the only one who see God in eternity. Now, in eternity, Jesus has no flesh yet, while on earth, Jesus enters the fullness of time. So, who sees God in eternity? The soul of Jesus sees God in eternity. This is quite tricky, because if we say the Logos sees God in eternity and not the soul of Jesus, then we will have a problem with hypostatic union, as the Logos and the human soul of Jesus is distinct with each other. It would seem that Trinity and the soul of Jesus existed in eternity and ofcourse the soul of Mary existed in eternity too, as the Madonna is God's vision.Ave!

Eastern Orthodox (EO) here, interesting question. I think I have to give a long answer to explain properly. But I'll try to put a short one at the bottom as well.
I dislike both of your suggested solutions.

Was it like His divine soul simply entered His created human soul and the two joined as one, and thus, showing no contradictions to each other and abiding in perfect harmony and agreement, can be considered one soul, one personality?

I cannot agree because "joined as one" is unclear, 1 personality (what do you mean by personality?), and the Human Nature was assumed/added to the Word (God the Son)

Or is it like, rather, in case with Jesus there is only His uncreated divine soul that Christ has always possessed eternally, and the absence of a created human soul does not exclude Him from being fully human (just as the absence of a biological human father does not)?

I cannot agree because this neglects Jesus' human nature in favor of his divine nature.
Of the two, the first is more accurate. But needs to be polished to not be confused with various christological heresies.

Who is Jesus?
The scriptures say that Jesus is the unique Son of God, but also the Son of Man, who is the Christ.
We are first directly introduced to Christ in the new testament. With his very unique birth. Jesus is conceived in the womb of Mary by the power of the Holy Spirit (Matthew 1:18-25; Isaiah 7:14; Luke 1:35-38). Not only this, but Jesus is without sin (2 Corinthians 5:21; 1 John 3:5l; 1 Peter 2:22). Jesus is unique, not only in his birth, and life, but by his nature. The designations of Christ
reveal more fully who he is. The first thing worth pointing to is the title: “The Son of God.” There is a two fold sense in which Jesus is the Son of God,
first by his nature (ontologically), and secondly in his works (functionally).
In the old testament that title was for the people of Israel at times, for the king who would act as God's chosen agent, with promises of God's paternity and love (like in 2 Samuel 7:14-16) It was generally a privilege for kings, but it was a foreshadowing of the coming King Jesus.
Jesus is not merely a Son because he was incarnate, but rather he was the only unique Son of God who became incarnate.
So we understand the "Fully Divine" aspect. What of the human side?
Jesus used the term "Son of Man" quite frequently, 80+ times in the new testament, the title highlights Jesus as the God-man King. This is demonstrated in Daniel 7:13-14, which speaks of a Son of Man who rides the clouds and receives all authority. This Son-King becomes a means of restoring God's creation and rules over it.
Another title "The Christ" or "The Messiah". That is to say the anointed one, anointed by the Holy Spirit was to function as the King and priest over Israel. He is God's chosen agent for bringing about the kingdom.
All of that helps us start to have some insight into the narrative surrounding Jesus as well as his identity.

Before delving deeper in to the Christology here, a historical note is required. The Orthodox Church recognizes all 7 ecumenical councils before the Great Schism in 1054 AD. Before this event, the church was one and united against many heresies and became more and more refined in the specifics of the teachings. That is to say, when a heresy popped up, the church had to understand it and then refute it and be able to clearly say how/why. For the Orthodox church, we do use the writings of the Saints and Church fathers before us to help guide us. (We learn from history)
I mention this because many of the heresies were related to Christ. As well as to point out that the church has temporally stated things that were true both before and after they were declared.


The first major event is the 1st Council of Nicaea in 325. Where Arianism (Christ is not truly divine, and is the first created being) was refuted.

The 1st Council of Ephesus in 431 dealt with Nestorianism (Christ consisted of two separate persons 1 human 1 divine) this council declared that Jesus is fully God and fully Man. (This should also deal with Docetism: Jesus only appeared human, as well as the opposite version which was Ebionism which claimed Jesus was a normal human empowered by the Holy Spirit)

The Council of Chalcedon in 451 dealt with Monophystism which rejects the human nature of Jesus by claiming the Divine aspect consumed or overwhelmed the human side. This council declared that Jesus is perfect God and perfect Man and that Jesus unites divinity and humanity within Himself as a single person, infused and immutable, yet indivisible and inseparable. (It should also reject by association Apollinarianism which says Jesus' human spirit was replaced, as well as Adoptionism which is similar, in addition this council should also be applicable to Ontological Kenoticism which claims at the incarnation Jesus emptied himself of divine attributes)

The 3rd Council of Constantinople in 680-681 dealt with Monothelitism, which taught that Jesus had 2 natures but only one will. That is to say He did not have a human will. The council noted that Jesus has 2 natures, will is attributed to natures, therefore he has two wills, yet the human will is submissive to his divine will.


There are 3 other major councils, but the five mentioned are the ones most relevant to your question.
So we see from the Church councils that Jesus is Uncreated, fully perfectly God and fully perfectly Human, perfectly combines those natures within Himself, is indivisible, and has 2 wills.

In your question you refer to "soul" but I think from our understanding we would say "nature". You point out that being human includes having a human soul, but your definition is a little off by our standard. You assign "will" to the soul, but that's not how this works. A soul/nature(spirit does not act, it is the person who acts through their nature (or with their soul) that is acting. A nature is what "being, essence, or substance" something is. Likewise a person's soul is not "the person" itself.

A definition of the soul as provided by Saint John the Damascan: ‘The soul, therefore, is a living essence, uncomplicated, incorporeal, invisible – in its proper nature – to the eyes of the body, immortal, reasoning and intelligent, formless, making use of an organic body and being the source of its powers of life, growth, sensation and generation, the intellect being its purest part though not in any way alien to it (as the eye is to the body, so the intellect is to the soul). It has power over itself, its volition and energy, and is mutable, i.e. able to be changed, because it is created. All of these features are natural to it through the Grace imparted by its Creator, and its being and nature are thus because of this same Grace which it has received’. (What is the soul?)

Note that the word above being translated to "intellect" is the word "nous" which is not a satisfactory translation.

Metropolitan Kallistos Ware calls it "the highest faculty in man, through which - provided it is purified - he knows God or the inner essences of principles of created beings by means of direct apprehension or spiritual perception" (Ibid)

So a person's nature includes their soul, their essence. And a person is "the who" that is existing and acting through a nature and its capacities.

The next important thing to understand is the Trinity, Unlike us humans God is 3 persons existing (subsisting) in the single divine Nature. (The One ontological God) They all operate inseparably, but each work is specifically attributed or appropriated to one of Them. Each person is in their own right, God in himself, and each person is identical with the others in all things except their personal properties. (Paternity, Filiation, and Spiration)
So this groundwork lets us understand why the Son became enfleshed/incarnate. The Son is the person who acts through His divine nature, but becomes incarnate, and thus acts through two natures in His ministry for the Triniy's work in redemption.
The Sonship of Christ is not created in the incarnation of the Word (Logos), but the Word is the Son who becomes incarnate. The Son was with the Father in Eternity, and there was never a time when the Son was not. (John 1:1-18, 17:5+24, Hebrews 1:1-4, Colossians 1:15-17, Revelations 19:13, ...)
Incarnation comes from the latin text of John 1:14 and literally means taking flesh. The term would eventually summarize the doctrine of the Eternal Son adding to himself a human nature.
The Son (the person) still possesses his fundamental divine nature, but assumes a human nature and acts through it. This nature is not a person, it cannot act independently, but it is assumed by the person (The Son). This means a new human nature was created by God to be assumed by the Son for the redemptive purpose.
As a Truly God and truly man, whenever Christ acts it is the divine Son acting in and through his two natures. There is no union of these two natures that is "blended or mixed", because that would change what divinity or humanity is. (To claim that they are "mixed" or that Christ has "one nature that is of the two combined", is Eutychianism or Miaphysitism respectfully)

Gregory of Nazianzus summarized "That which Christ did not assume , he did not heal" (Famous quote from "St Gregory’s letter to Cledonius")

So when we observe the life of Jesus we remember that he is living life as a human (that nature he assumed) as the second Adam for the sake of redeeming human beings. He assumed a human mind, will, soul, etc. and lived as a man in obedience to the Father unto death for our sake (Phil. 2:5-11). (This is why there are moments in the Bible where Jesus seems "lesser" to the Father, but that is Christ living in accordance with his human nature.

I cannot explain all of Orthodox Christology in this answer, but I hope I've explained enough to answer your question.

Short answer / Conclusion
The Divine Person of The Son is eternal. The assumed (added to Himself) human nature (mind, soul, etc.) occurred (from our perspective) at the incarnation of the Word. This means that Humanity is now closer to God then ever before because God the Son is also Human. (See Orthodox Salvation and Theosis for another long topic about why this is really important)

"Both of your proposed conclusions are unacceptable, because they both reject that Jesus is fully God and fully Man" - How do both of them, especially the first one, reject that Jesus is fully God and fully Man???

@brilliant Because "the two joined as one" is Eutychianism or Miaphysitism depending on how want to explain that. The two natures remained two, including the human soul, within the person of the Word Incarnate, Jesus. If they became 1 "soul" as you say, it creates a 3rd nature or it ruins the divine and human nature. "There is no union of these two natures that is "blended or mixed", because that would change what divinity or humanity is. (To claim that they are "mixed" or that Christ has "one nature that is of the two combined", is Eutychianism or Miaphysitism respectfully)"

Where did I say that "the two joined as one" means that the two natures - divine and human - were mixed and produced a third nature???

@brilliant "His divine soul simply entereded His created human soul and the two joined as one" When you say part of His divine nature and His human nature were joined as one, you are combining the natures together.

"When you say part of His divine nature and His human nature were joined as one, you are combining the natures together" - Combining doesn't mean mixing! Nor does it mean that any one of His two natures disappeared or produced together a third nature.

@brilliant "You said "joined as one" maybe rephrase that part so it is clear. Because it instantly made me think of "oh, two become one, just like in marriage"

Even in marriage the husband remains a male, and the wife remains a female.

@brilliant I cannot make you rephrase it so your text is less confusing to me. I can only ask.

Jesus Christ soul was created as it enters time, but also already existed in the bosoms of the Father in eternity, as the Father is not subject to time. See my full answer below.

Not just Easter Orthodox I would add. +1.

I write as a Trinitarian Protestant. I think neither of the OP's two options are Biblical.
Also (please humour my pickyness for a minute) the terminology is suspect: I'm not sure but believe the word "soul" is never used of any being that has no physical body.  So, in scripture, animals have souls, and humans, but not angels nor God.  Scripturally, I think it is true, someone can prove me wrong, all souls are spirits, but not all spirits are souls. If I am wrong then surely in most cases souls relate to physical bodies: it is much preferable to keep to Biblical definitions, especially when so much confusion arises because of different definitions of words. (After physical death, the soul is kept in an unnatural state, separate from the physical body designed for it to inhabit, until the day of resurrection.)
The conundrum the OP raises can be helped by looking at a few passages of scripture.  Does not the soul include the attributes of the desires, the memory and knowledge, and the will?
The passage that first comes to mind is our Lord's struggles in the Garden of Gethsemane.  Here, our Lord prayed

Father, if thou be willing, remove this cup from me: nevertheless, not my will, but thine be done, Luke 22:42.

Here it can be seen that our Lord Jesus does not have a single composite will of both human and divine: as man he has one will, and as the Son of God he has a different will. He brings himself, by much intense prayer, to submit to the Divine will. So we see our Lord humbled himself and became obedient unto death, even the death of the cross, Phil 2:8.
He was not born with the fallen human nature which you and I have: but he was born with a human will which he brought into subjection to the divine will.  Nor did he call upon the assistance of his Divine nature to help in his battle against sin.. he didn't turn stones into bread in the desert when he was hungry; he went through the difficulties of temptation by prayer and obedience to the word of God.. what I mean is the temptations were not made easier to his human nature by the union of it with his Divine nature.

For we have not a High Priest who cannot be touched with the feeling of our infirmities; but he was in all points tempted like as we are, but without sin, Hebrews 4:15.

Seeing as God cannot be tempted to sin, it follows our Lord had a separate human nature.

But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels which are in heaven, neither the Son, but my Father, Mark 13:32.

Our Lord Jesus tells us he is God. As God the Son he knew and knows everything.  But as man he did not know everything.. he tells us so himself.  His human experience was that he knew everything his Father chose to reveal to him.  His human nature was not absorbed into his divine nature, they were not so united as to make a single composite soul, with a single knowledge, a single will or a single desire.
He humbled himself and became obedient to the Divine will, even unto death.  It was not any easier because he had a Divine nature.
And because he was fully human, as well as fully God, his human soul came into existence at the same time as every other human being, at conception.
What proves he was Divine is his language, saying things that only God can say.  If he was not God the things he said were blasphemy.  No man ever spake like this man!  Of course not.  No man else was and is also God.

If anything having "divine" power would make temptation greater, all that power...

@Wyrsa - I hadn't thought of that.... I guess you mean "All that power in his Divine nature he could have called upon to help him in his hours of temptation"?  His temptations were greater (than ours in the same situation) because he was tempted to call, but he never did: eg "Put away your sword. Do you not know I could call upon my Father, and He would send immediately more than twelve legions of angels", Matthew 26:53.

"I'm not sure but believe the word "soul" is never used of any being that has no physical body" - Rev. 6:9 "When he opened the fifth seal, I saw under the altar the SOULS of those who had been slain because of the word of God and the testimony they had maintained" - these ones have no physical bodies anymore because they have already been killed.

@brilliant - Very true.  But, as I claim in my answer, it is an "unnatural state" without the body.  True though.

"it is much preferable to keep to Biblical definitions" - The problem is, just like you yourself mention, Biblical definitions are not definitions, but simply terms that have multiple meanings depending on the context and the interpretation. "Soul" is one of them. At times it means "a human" in the Bible, at other times, "animal", at other times "life" and so on. That's why I decided to go by way of using the term "soul" in "my own way", that is, providing my own definition - the ability to have thoughts, emotions and will (decisions, desires, resoulutions, etc.)

I did say I was being a bit "picky".  I don't think the scriptures use soul for God or angels though... or can you find where it does ?  And because the scriptures use in many ways I'm just pleading we try to restrict usage within the bounds set by it.
